# How to print out Name instead of ID using SQL INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Actually i don't know how i can get this done, as this is my first time of having to do this. Am having 2 tables in my DB.

```
Table 1 users
Table 2 Transfer History.
```

here is my code:

```
SELECT u.id
     , u.fname
     , u.lname
     , t.sender_id
     , t.beneficiary_id
     , t.amount
     , t.date_posted 
  from transfers t
  JOIN users u
    ON u.id = t.sender_id 
 WHERE u.id = '".$id."' 
 ORDER 
    BY t.date_posted DESC
```

and i echo out the details using

```
                                    <?php $i = 1; while($row = ): ?>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><?= $i++ ?></td>
                                                <td><?= $row['sender'] ?></td>
                                                <td><?= $row['sender'] ?></td>
                                                <td><?= $i++ ?></td>
                                                <td><?= $i++ ?></td>
                                            </tr>
                                    <?php endwhile ?>
```

Instead of echoing out the beneficiary_id i want to echo out the beneficiary name from the users DB

Comment: Are you sure that the give php command prints out beneficiary_id? because the code does not show so.

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query). Also, see about sql injection, and the importance of prepared and bound queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not everyone is aware that, with databases, there is no rule that you may only join a table into a query once. It looks like you need to join users in twice, one for the person who sent the payment and once for the person who received it:

```
    SELECT 
      su.fname as sender_fname,
      su.lname as sender_lname,
      bu.fname as beneficiary_fname,
      bu.lname as beneficiary_lname,
      t.sender_id,
      t.beneficiary_id,
      t.amount,
      t.date_posted
  FROM
    transfers t
    JOIN users su ON su.id = t.sender_id 
    JOIN users bu ON bu.id = t.beneficiary_id 
  WHERE su.id = '".$id."' 
  ORDER BY t.date_posted DESC
```

Your query resultset now contains the names of both the sender and the receiver, and they are aliased differently so you can refer to one or the other in your php using the alias

It's important to note that you can't get away with mentioning the user table just once, and using OR (you can't say `ON u.id = t.sender_id OR u.id = t.beneficiary_id`) because this will cause the number of *rows* ro increase - you'll get two rows per transfer. For ease of reference of "this payment was sent from this person to that person" you want the number of *columns* to increase, not the number of rows. For 100 payments, you want a resultset that is "100 rows of two columns; a from and a to" you don't want "200 rows of one column containing both from and to, on different rows"